# Yelp authentication in http headers

Tags: swift, oauth, yelp, hmacsha1

I'm simply trying to search for business location using the yelp api (https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/authentication). However, I am unable to authenticate with their service despite adding the required fields to the header. Here is the code:

```
    private func generateAuthorizationHeaders() -> String {
    let consumer = "oauth_consumer_key=\"\(consumerKey!)\""
    let accessToken = "oauth_token=\"\(token!)\""
    let signatureMethod = "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\""
    let signature = "oauth_signature=\"\(token!.hmacsha1(key: tokenSecret!))\"" //More than likely wrong
    let timestamp = "oauth_timestamp=\"\(Int(Date.timeIntervalBetween1970AndReferenceDate))\""
    let uniqueString = "oauth_nonce=\"nvgnhvfvfvffvvf\""
    return "\(consumer),\(accessToken),\(signatureMethod),\(signature),\(timestamp),\(uniqueString)"
}

func search(for place: String, at location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let authorization = generateAuthorizationHeaders()
    let string = "https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=\(place)&ll=\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: string) as! URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("\(authorization)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
       ... JSON stuff
    }).resume()
```

The error message I am receiving is:

```
{
error =     {
    field = "oauth_consumer_key";
    id = "MISSING_PARAMETER";
    text = "One or more parameters are missing in request";
};
```

}

Can someone spot the problem? thank you.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, Yelp is quite lacking in the API documentation department and has outdated SDK examples but I'll let you know if I make any headway.

Answer (score 0):

*Nearly two years later*

Looks like your missing the `OAuth`.

Try this:

```
return "OAuth \(consumer),\(accessToken),\(signatureMethod),\(signature),\(timestamp),\(uniqueString)
```